# Load Image From URL is Displaying But I Can't Retrieve It

Tags: swift

I have an extension to UIImageView that loads an image from an external URL as follows:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func load(url: URL) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling it into a table cell as shown below:

```
let imgUrl = URL(string: "\(K.liveAssetEnpoint)/studio/mbr/1/\(slideId ?? "")/img/\(self.elementArr[indexPath.row].imageName)")
cell.layerImage.load(url: imgUrl!)
```

The class for the table cell I am loading it into looks like this:

```
import UIKit
class ElementLayerDataCell : UITableViewCell {

     let layerTitleText : UILabel = {
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.textColor = K.TextColors.title
        lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        lbl.textAlignment = .left
        return lbl
     }()

    let layerImage : UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        img.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return img
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        addSubview(layerTitleText)
        addSubview(layerImage)
        layerTitleText.anchor(top: topAnchor,
                             left: leftAnchor,
                             bottom: nil,
                             right: nil,
                             paddingTop: 5,
                             paddingLeft: 5,
                             paddingBottom: 0,
                             paddingRight: 0,
                             width: frame.size.width / 2,
                             height: 0,
                             enableInsets: false)
        layerImage.anchor(top: topAnchor,
                             left: leftAnchor,
                             bottom: nil,
                             right: nil,
                             paddingTop: 5,
                             paddingLeft: 5,
                             paddingBottom: 0,
                             paddingRight: 0,
                             width: 50,
                             height: 50,
                             enableInsets: false)
     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }

}
```

The image loads fine and is displayed as expected. My question is why am I then unable to retrieve the resulting image from the class like so:

```
let newImage = self.elementArr[indexPath.row].imageView.image
print("newImage: \(newImage)")
```

The above results in the following:

```
newImage: nil
```

I need to reuse the image in a different view and want to avoid invoking the load function twice. Can anybody please let me know what I am missing? I can't find anything covering this online.

Thanks.

Comment: Is elementArr an array of cells?

Comment: Your approach is very bad practice. 1) Never load data with synchronous `Data(contentsOf:` API, not even on a background thread. 2) Never misuse an UI element like `UIImageView` as data model. It's highly recommended to use a download manager which loads the images asynchronously and caches them.

Comment: Have accepted the answer from Elhoej as it was what I requested but am also looking into reworking my code using SDWebimage. Thanks for the info vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an image cache and cache the image when downloaded. Then check the cache to see if the image is already there before initiating the download. In the following exmaple I simply use the url string as the key identifier to save the image.

Create an image cache:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()
```

Check if image is already cached, if not download the image and save it in cache:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func load(url: URL) {

        let urlString = url.absoluteString

        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```